# How to set proxy details from twittersearch stream of Spring XD?

Tags: spring-xd

I have set up a single node Spring XD and running the XD Shell. The hosts running these are not exposed to internet due to which I am not able to use the twittersearch stream which is out of box from Spring XD. It throws ***java.net.UnknownHostException: api.twitter.com***

Now my question is, how do I set my proxy details to Spring XD so it can use them to reach out to Twitter?

Comment: Please tell us what you have trired so far.

Comment: I made sure I am able to cURL https://api.twitter.com from the server my SpringXD is running on, of course by exporting my proxy server details. I tried adding my proxy details in the twittersearch.properties and twittersearch.xml files in /spring-xd-1.0.0.RELEASE/xd/modules/source/twittersearch/config directory, but it did not help. I tried finding an answer in the Spring forum, Stackoverflow and internet in general, I could not find anything. I went through SpringXD Guide as well, the document from Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running single node in verbose mode you'll see an number of properties that have been set from environment variables such as `HTTP_PROXY`. There are also a number that will require Java arguments to be past in such `-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost`.  Try setting these in `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=` in the xd-singlenode script.

Comment: Thank you Paul! Setting the -Dhttps.proxyHost and -Dhttps.proxyPort to DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS in the xd-singlenode script WORKED!! Although HTTPS_PROXY showed up when I ran with verbose, the XD process could not take it.